# finding the range of values for a constant such that a certain function does not take the value zero

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$$f(x) = \frac{3x^2 +4x-4}{1-x},\\y_3=f(x) + C,\\y_2=f(x+K).$$

How would I go about to find the range of values to see that $y_3$ does not take the value zero?

How would I find the constant value of $K$ such that $y_2$ is not defined at $x=0$?

For this one I took it to mean that the function would become undefined when $x=0$ and there is the correct value of $K$ so I equated the denominator with $0$ which went something like:

$$1-x-K=0$$
$$1-K=0$$
$$K=1.$$ Is this correct?

Original Questions:

> Given that $y_2=f(x + K)$ and $y_3=f(x)+ C$ find:
>
> - the value of constant $K$ such that $y_2$ is not defined at $x=0$
> - the range of values of the constant $C$ such that $y_3$ does not take the value $0$

Comment: it must be $$x\ne 1$$

Comment: This question is vague for me!

Comment: solve the equation $$\frac{3x^2+4x-4}{1-x}=C$$